# MultiThreading RayTracer generating strange artifacts with plane

Tags: c++, multithreading, graphics, raytracing

I am currently implementing multi threading on my RayTracer and weird image artifacts started to show up in one of my test cases. The other three seem to be working fine. I will show the images.

Normal Single Thread:

[image: Z-single-thread.jpg]

[image: triangle.jpg]

Multi threading:

[image: image.jpg]

[image: triangles-_MT.jpg]

Multi threading, other run:

[image: plane.jpg]

[image: triangle.jpg]

What I am doing is to switch between pixels between two threads. Thread 0 gets par pixels (0,2,4,6) and Thread 1 gets pixels (1,3,5,9)

As can be seen, there are lot light greenish-blueish artifacts and variations among two multithreading runs, like the placement and quantity of the little dot like artifacts, plus the triangle color.

I send the program to print some variable data and this is what I received:

ST:

> BOTO x: 402 y 405
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405
>
> BOTO x: 404 y 405
>
> ......
>
> ......
>
> BOTO x: 405 y 407
>
> BOTO x: 406 y 407
>
> BOTO x: 407 y 407

Now this is the result of a 1° MT run:

> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1
>
> ....
>
> ....
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405 thread_id: 1

And this of a 2° run:

> BOTO x: 401 y 405
>
> BOTO x: 403 y 405
>
> BOTO x: 405 y 405
>
> ......
>
> ......
>
> BOTO x: 404 y 407
>
> BOTO x: 406 y 407
>
> BOTO x: 408 y 407

So what I have here is a MT code that is executing differently on each time, as the different images showed to be a case. The 2° MT run executes correctly (without repeated messages of the screen coordinates) for the screen coordinates that I showed, as the ST case, but exhibited the same behavior on other coordinates.

More strange is that if a just send the MT setup code to execute the same algorithm as the ST version, or in another words, to render the same image twice, the problem persists. And changes a bit.

[image: ST-_MT1.jpg]

[image: ST-_MT2.jpg]

As can be seen, executing the same code with MT sometimes gets a "clean" area in the beginning and the triangle gets dark (although I think its possible that the same could happen with the original MT code, especially the "dark" triangle stuff).

I would appreciate any suggestions on how I shall try to diagnose the problem, because I do not possess any idea to what the source of issues it is, if is MT setup code related or algorithm problem. I would bet in MT setup code, since it is I changed the algorithm to the same of ST version and there is still issues. However, the issues changed a little bit, so I am lost here.

RT algorithm code that is related to the MT support:

```
 void RayTracer::draw_multithread (Image *image, Scene *scene, int thread_id) {

  float inv_div=0.5;
  int ctr=0;
  int y=0;
  int initial_x=0;
  if (thread_id==1) {
    cout << "thread_1" << endl;
  ctr=1024*384;
  y=384;
  inv_div=1;
  }

 //if (thread_id==1)
  // return;

 for (; y<(float)image->getHeight()*inv_div; y++) {
   //float px = px_inicial;
   //py = py + ystep;
   for (int x=initial_x; x<image->getWidth(); x++) {
   ....
   .....
      b [ctr] = min (blue*255.0f,255.0f);
      c [ctr] = min (green*255.0f,255.0f);
      d [ctr] = min (red*255.0f,255.0f);
      ctr++;
   }
 }
pthread_exit (NULL);   
}

MT code:

pthread_t threads [2];
thread_data td_array [2];
void *status;
TGAManager tgaManager ("z.tga",true);
if (tgaManager.isFileOpen()) {
   tgaManager.writeHeadersData (image);
   RayTracer rt (image.getHeight() * image.getWidth(),1);
   int rc;
   for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
      //cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      td_array[i].thread_id=i;
      td_array[i].rt_ptr = &rt;
      td_array[i].img_ptr = &image;
      td_array[i].scene_ptr = &scene;
     //cout << "td_array.thread_index: " << td_array[i].thread_id << endl;
     rc = pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, RayTracer::run_thread, &td_array[i]);
   }
   if (rc) {
     cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
     exit(-1);
   }
   for (int i=0; i<2; i++ ) {
     rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
     if (rc) {
        cout << "Error:unable to join," << rc << endl;
        exit(-1);
     }
   }

for (int i=0; i<image.getWidth() * image.getHeight(); i++) {
  tgaManager.file_writer.put (rt.b[i]);
  tgaManager.file_writer.put (rt.c[i]);
  tgaManager.file_writer.put (rt.d[i]);
}
tgaManager.closeFile(1);
rt.deleteImgPtr (true);
}
```

For more details: https://gitlab.com/asmf2/asmfrt/blob/master/RayTracer.cpp (last method from bottom to up) and https://gitlab.com/asmf2/asmfrt/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: Some actual code would be quite helpful.

Comment: Try nerfing out one of the threads so that only the other thread actually writes any pixels, and see if you get the half-image you would expect or not.  Then do the same thing again, except nerf out of the other thread.  If both threads on their own produce a "clean" half-image, then the problem must be with the merging of the two images.  OTOH if the half-images have artifacts as well, then the problem is unrelated to the multithreading.

Comment: check if pixelformat matches in image and pixel you write..... If you got 24bit RGBA and write 32bit pixel on single thread with linear access is all OK  but with non linear access you partialy overwrite neighboring pixel too ... Also it is better to divide/schedule the image by lines (line per thread)

Comment: All good points above. Also, I've found that dividing into tiles (32x32 empirically best) rather than single pixels or lines results in fastest performance, most likely due to cache locality.

Comment: meowgoesthedog, I added code.     Jeremy Friesner: I did what you suggested and the half-images are without artifact. But the full image is still problematic as before.    Spektre, not sure if I understood fully, but I am writing a char each time with the put function for each color channel, so 8*3bits = 24bits, so I think it's not the issue?     Daniel, interesting I might try it in the future when I have time